# Can I designate a Java-like 'constructor' in c?

Tags: c, constructor, struct, malloc, memset

I want to 'construct' (read: malloc and memset) my hashtable in c.  To do this, I created a function as follows:

```
int maketable(struct hash_entry **table, int size){

    table = (struct hash_entry **)malloc(size*sizeof(struct hash_entry *));
    int i = 0;
    for (; i<size; i++) {
        memset(table[i], '\0', sizeof(struct hash_entry *));
    }
    return 0;

}
```

Given that table will have been declared as

```
struct hash_entry **table[size]
```

before entering this code, I won't lose anything when I return from maketable, right?

EDIT:
Does passing `table` into `maketable()` ensure that as long as I change the data that `table` points to, the changes will be preserved?

EDIT II:
I am trying to allocate an array of pointers to pointers to hash_entries

Comment: I don't understand. You're allocating memory on stack for the variable and then reallocate something in the function? -- Besides, `table` is a local variable. You are allocating something and assigning it to `table` which will go away when the function returns, causing a memory leak.

Comment: The problem is that I don't quite understand either.  Does my declaration of struct hash_entry **table[size] implicitly allocate the memory for me?  In that case, I still have to malloc for the hash_entrys themselves when I declare them, right?

Comment: The declaration allocates memory for an array with size `size` of pointers to pointers of type `hash_entry` on stack. It doesn't allocate memory for the locations that array elements are going to point to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is assigning to the local `table` variable, the caller is not affected. This results in a memory leak.

Outside the function, you have declared table as an array of pointer to pointers of struct hash_entry - I'm guessing you rather just want an array of pointers to struct hash entries.

If you actually declare `table` as an array, there's no need to malloc that space. You just need a loop to set every element in it to NULL (Don't memset each element to zeroes).

If the goal is to allocate the entire table, this is perhps what you're looking for:

```
struct hash_entry **table;
...
int maketable(struct hash_entry ***table, int size){

    *table = malloc(size* sizeof **table);
    int i = 0;
    for (; i<size; i++) {
       (*table)[i] = NULL;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

call it like

```
maketable(&table,100);
```

I'd rather make that return the table like so:

```
struct hash_entry ** maketable(int size){
   return calloc(size, sizeof(struct hash_entry *));
}
```

if the declaration `struct hash_entry **table[size]` is really what you want, you need to tell us what your maketable() function actually is supposed to do (e.g. do you want to a dynamically allocated 'array' as one of the elements in that table ?

Answer (score 2):

You will need to assign the result of `malloc` to `* table` - otherwise it won't be visible outside the function.

Also, the typical way of using this is to declare a pointer to the hashtable and pass the *address* of that pointer into the function.

Comment: `* table = (struct hash_entry *) malloc ...`

Answer (score 1):

No.  Your types don't match up.

Are you trying to allocate a table of hash entries (i.e., the type of `table[i]` is `struct hash_entry`), a table of *pointers* to hash_entries (i.e., the type of `table[i]` is `struct hash_entry *`), or something else?  Based on how your code reads, I'm assuming the first case, but let me know if that's wrong.

Assuming you're dynamically allocating a table of `struct hash_entry`, your declaration of the table in the caller should be

```
struct hash_entry *table; // 1 *, no array dimension
```

the function should be *called* as

```
int result = maketable(&table, number_of_elements);
```

and *defined* as

```
int maketable (struct hash_entry **table, size_t size)
{
  int r = 0;

  // sizeof **table == sizeof (struct hash_entry)
  *table = malloc(sizeof **table * size);
  // *ALWAYS* check the result of malloc()
  if (*table)
  {
    size_t i;
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
      memset(&(*table)[i], 0, sizeof (*table)[i]);
    r = 1;
  }
  return r;
}
```

A couple of things to point out.  First of all, don't cast the result of `malloc()`.  As of C89, you don't need to, and the cast will supress a diagnostic if you forget to include stdlib.h or otherwise don't have a prototype for `malloc()` in scope.  Secondly, you can use the `sizeof` operator on objects instead of types.  This can help reduce some maintenance headaches (i.e., if you change the type of `table` in the parameter list, you don't have to change the `sizeof` calls along with it).

Finally, note that the *address* of table is being passed to the function; since we're trying to write to a *pointer value*, we must pass a pointer to that pointer.

If you were attempting to create a table of pointers to `struct hash_entry`, the code is mostly the same, just an extra level of indirection:

your declaration of the table in the caller should be

```
struct hash_entry **table; // 2 *, no array dimension
```

the function should be *called* as

```
int result = maketable(&table, number_of_elements);
```

and *defined* as

```
int maketable (struct hash_entry ***table, size_t size)
{
  int r = 0;

  // sizeof **table == sizeof (struct hash_entry *)
  *table = malloc(sizeof **table * size);
  // *ALWAYS* check the result of malloc()
  if (*table)
  {
    size_t i;
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
      (*table)[i] = NULL;
    r = 1;
  }
  return r;
}
```

**EDIT** There was a bug in the `maketable` examples; `table` needs to be dereferenced before applying the subscript, i.e., `(*table)[i]`.   We're applying the subscript to what `table` *points to*, not the table pointer itself.

Sorry for any confusion.

Comment: I am trying to allocate a table of pointers to pointers to hash_entries.

Comment: Then you need to declare the table as `struct hash_entry ***table;`.  The type of the parameter in the function needs to be `struct hash_entry ****table`.  Everything else should be the same as the second example.